# Custom component not rendering properly anymore

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm new to creating custom components on `android` and it was a fun, annoying, and very educational experience. I was able to make my quite complex custom component and I'm very happy with it. But after I moved it to a directory and out of it, it doesn't display anything anymore.

My project consist of a lot of `fragments` and my custom component is used on one of them. So when I moved all those `fragments` in a directory, AS told me that someone can't find something on my custom component class. So I included the custom component class inside the fragments directory. Everything worked fine but when I tried to use the custom view on a different layout which is not a `fragment`'s, the custom component doesn't display anything. I made every variable of the custom view class to public then moved it outside the fragments folder. Now, it doesn't display anything anymore. Please point out what I've done wrong.

This is custom component class.

```
public class CheckOutItem extends ConstraintLayout {
    public Context ctx;
    public Paint mPaint;
    public Rect mRect;
    int mSquareColor;
    public ImageView imgThumbnail;
    public TextView lblAbbrev, lblFullName;
    public ConstraintLayout lytMain;

    public CheckOutItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ctx = context;
        init(null);
    }

    public CheckOutItem(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.checkout_item, this);
        ctx = context;

        init(attrs);
    }

    public CheckOutItem(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        ctx = context;
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet set){
        inflate(ctx, R.layout.checkout_item, this);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mRect = new Rect();

        if(set == null){
            return;
        }

        TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(set, R.styleable.CheckOutItem);

        this.imgThumbnail = findViewById(R.id.imgItemThumbnail);
        this.lblAbbrev = findViewById(R.id.lblItemAbbrevName);
        this.lblFullName = findViewById(R.id.lblItemFullName);
        this.lytMain = findViewById(R.id.lytMain);

        this.lblAbbrev.setText(ta.getText(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_abbrevText));
        this.lblAbbrev.setTextSize(ta.getDimension(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_abbrevTextSize, 1f));
        this.lblAbbrev.setTextColor(ta.getColor(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_abbrevTextColor, Color.BLACK));

        this.lblFullName.setText(ta.getText(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_fullNameText));
        this.lblFullName.setTextSize(ta.getDimension(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_fullNameTextSize, 1f));
        this.lblFullName.setTextColor(ta.getColor(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_fullNameTextColor, Color.BLACK));
        this.lblFullName.setBackgroundColor(ta.getColor(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_fullNameBackgroundColor, Color.WHITE));

        this.lytMain.setBackgroundColor(ta.getColor(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_mainBackgroundColor, Color.LTGRAY));

        ta.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mRect.left = 0;
        mRect.right = getWidth();
        mRect.top = 0;
        mRect.bottom = getHeight();

        canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);
    }
}
```

This is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_bg">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgItemThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[9]"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblItemAbbrevName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblItemFullName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblItemAbbrevName"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</merge>
```

This is my attrs.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CheckOutItem">
        <attr name="thumbnail" format="string"/>
        <attr name="abbrevText" format="string"/>
        <attr name="abbrevTextSize" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="abbrevTextColor" format="color|reference"/>
        <attr name="fullNameText" format="string"/>
        <attr name="fullNameTextSize" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="fullNameTextColor" format="color|reference"/>
        <attr name="textStyle">
            <enum name="normal" value="0"/>
            <enum name="bold" value="1"/>
            <enum name="italic" value="2"/>
        </attr>
        <attr name="fullNameBackgroundColor" format="color|reference"/>
        <attr name="mainBackgroundColor" format="color|reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This is how I use it.

```
<com.example.android.projectname.CheckOutItem
        android:id="@+id/coi2"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        android:layout_margin="7.8dp"
        app:abbrevText="MP"
        app:abbrevTextColor="@color/black"
        app:abbrevTextSize="12sp"
        app:fullNameBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fullNameText="Make Payment"
        app:fullNameTextColor="@color/white"
        app:fullNameTextSize="8sp"
        app:mainBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
        app:thumbnail="" />
```

Comment: is `onDraw` called at all? what do you see if you add `Log.d(TAG, "rect: " + mRect);` inside?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be called.

Comment: so you have the answer on why you dont see anything...  what is the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top` command? - i mean only the view tree hierarchy

Comment: hi, I've already found the answer. Quite a petty problem, poor me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inflating your layout twice

```
public CheckOutItem(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.checkout_item, this);
    ...
```

Remove the second inflate in `init`

```
private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet set){
    // inflate(ctx, R.layout.checkout_item, this); // remove this line
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Didn't know that's what is causing it. But why did it work before?

Comment: @rminaj Are you sure that it worked before with exactly the same code? if yes, could it be that you have updated the SDK and it's not accepted anymore like before?

Comment: Yes, as I've mentioned on my question, it worked before. I update AS to 3.4.1 because I thought it would fix my problem with the layout editor. I think the moving of the custom view class screwed something up.